# Lock resources in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I am working under eclipse plugin right now.
Is there any way to lock resources in workspace, so it would be not possible to do any manipulations(delete, rename) with them.

For example I have some folder in eclipse workspace and I know that this folder shouldn't be changed by using import or delete action, can I somehow tell eclipse to disable such actions of show errors while such actions are occurred.

Comment: There has to be a way because Eclipse itself hides the directory you compile your classes into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set that folders write permissions to read only on your filesystem and that would affect Eclipse, too.

Exactly how do you do that depends on your operating system. If it is Windows, I think that right click on that folder > Properties > check the read only option (or similar).

If you use a Unix-like OS, then see `chmod` and `chown` commands.